# Implement shell history in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to implement something similar to shell history, where if you press the up arrow key it brings the last command. The two main problems I have encountered:

1. How to detect the up arrow key
2. How to print the last command, so that the user will be able to edit it in real time and press enter to give input to the program, instead of just printing it.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use the [`Readline`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Your question in very unspecific but I'm going to answer because I did a very similar pet project in the past: **[YARR](https://github.com/arturoherrero/yarr)**.

As Stefan commented you can use the [Readline](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html) module. You can check my commits from the beginning to know how I did it.